# Facebook share dialog javascript

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I am trying to use the Facebook share dialog and, to do so, the Facebook JS SDK seems to need an app. So I create my app with the "website" type but the forms to get it validated ask me a lot of informations about the Facebook login (a description of the process, some screenshots,...), informations I can't give because I'm not using a Facebook login... and these fields are mandatory... you can see my problem now...

Is there a way to use the share dialog without configuring useless infos or without using an app to to so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to fill in App Details if you just are using the share dialog

Comment: Yes thank you. I couldn't make it live because i haven't filled the contact email. I thought it was because of the validation of the app. My bad...